# Maven relative path seemed to resolve to a concatentation of 2 full paths

Tags: windows, eclipse, maven

I have the following pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.globalfoundries.pdk.dm</groupId>
<artifactId>pdk-swtcommon</artifactId>
<version>1.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>PDK SWT Common</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.globalfoundries.pdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdk-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <relativePath>../pdk-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

...
</project>
```

When I do an Maven Clean, I got an error that seems to concatenate the full path for the pdk-parent/pom.xml into the current path where it complaints about non-readable POM and the path that is was given is:
\MPTFS04\cley\Profile\Perforce\pdk-workspace\pdk-qa\shared\dev\DEV\java\pdk-swtcommon\MPTFS04\cley\Profile\Perforce\pdk-workspace\pdk-qa\shared\dev\DEV\java\pdk-parent\pom.xml

Well, \MPTFS04\cley\Profile\Perforce\pdk-workspace\pdk-qa\shared\dev\DEV\java\pdk-swtcommon is where my current project and pom.xml is; and \MPTFS04\cley\Profile\Perforce\pdk-workspace\pdk-qa\shared\dev\DEV\java\pdk-parent\pom.xml is where the parent pdk-parent\pom.xml full path is...  I am running on a Windows 7 machine and those are the mounted network drive...  I am running the Maven build within Eclipse.

(see error below)

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were
>   encountered while processing the POMs: [FATAL] Non-readable POM
>   \MPTFS04\cley\Profile\Perforce\pdk-workspace\pdk-qa\shared\dev\DEV\java\pdk-swtcommon\MPTFS04\cley\Profile\Perforce\pdk-workspace\pdk-qa\shared\dev\DEV\java\pdk-parent\pom.xml:
>   \MPTFS04\cley\Profile\Perforce\pdk-workspace\pdk-qa\shared\dev\DEV\java\pdk-swtcommon\MPTFS04\cley\Profile\Perforce\pdk-workspace\pdk-qa\shared\dev\DEV\java\pdk-parent\pom.xml
>   (The system cannot find the path specified) @
>   \MPTFS04\cley\Profile\Perforce\pdk-workspace\pdk-qa\shared\dev\DEV\java\pdk-swtcommon\MPTFS04\cley\Profile\Perforce\pdk-workspace\pdk-qa\shared\dev\DEV\java\pdk-parent\pom.xml
>   @  [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]

Comment: Do you get the same errors when building from a command line rather than from eclipse?

Comment: @SteveC  Thanks for the suggestion...  I did and it has a totally different error.  I am following some leads to track that down...  Will see what I can find myself first.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `relativePath` element to:

```
<relativePath>../pdk-parent</relativePath>
```

Comment: It didn't work...  Interestingly, the error is so "slightly" different where the root folder has 2 slashes "\\MPTFS04" instead of previously with just 1 slash "\MPTFS04"...   Non-readable POM \\MPTFS04\cley\Profile\Perforce\pdk-workspace\pdk-qa\shared\dev\DEV\java\pdk-swtcommon\MPTFS04\cley\Profile\Perforce\pdk-workspace\pdk-qa\shared\dev\DEV\java\pdk-parent\pom.xml:...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally got it working for me....

My environments:
Version Control: Perforce
Windows 7
Eclipse Mars (4.5.2 Build 20160218-0600)
Maven Integration For Eclipse 1.6.2.20150902-0002

When I initially setup the projects
- My Perforce workspace is on the networked drive (\myfilesystem\mounted\joe...)
- My Eclipse workspace is on the C:\ drive.
I got the error that it is unable to find the "pom.xml" for the dependencies using the "relative path"...  I noticed that it was searching for "C:..." (the error on the console is using \myfilesystem\mounted\joe...  which threw me off; I only noticed that C:\ reference in a different place.)

Nevertheless, I re-setup a new Eclipse workspace on my network drive and redo everything...  Now it seems to be working.

Just FYI.